# iOS - Download json swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Good day.

I was faced with the task, can not find the answers on the internet, can anyone be able to help.

I need to send a request to the service. This request must be sent no more than 1 second once per hour. From the answer to the query to extract part of the data. When you receive or availability of this information, it should be added to the text box. Data should be stored and re-used after restarting the application.

To connect to the service, I use Alamofire. Help please, whether there is in this library any function to set the time limit, I request? And how to save the data? Save the new json file locally, or the data stored in an array, or use the database?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an idea of setting a time limit, but you can explore the [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer) function to check for that and if it is just a string that you want to store, you only need to use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) for that. It stores your data as a property list and you can access it from anywhere in the app at anytime.

Here's a [link](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/) to help you setup `NSUserDefaults`.